# Tips for first-time hikers

Tags: hiking

I'm going to be hiking for the first time, and it's going to be in a woody mountain in the backcountry, and I'd like to have some to-dos, not-to-dos, must-carries, and what precautions I should take while hiking in forests like this.

**Info that may be useful**:

- I'm a couch potato, I'm not fat but I'm not that dude who exercises a lot
- I walk 3 to 4 miles a day (I walk to work, it's not so far away and I get to enjoy some fresh air)
- I plan on hiking for a day, maybe two
- I bought some gear, like a backpack for campers, some knives, survival matches, some canned food (my favorite), a tarp, an iron pot for cooking, I'm not really sure of what kind of shoes I should wear, and I'm thinking about bringing a first aid kit on me as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is really your first time hiking, ever... then don't start out in the back country.  That's like doing your first climb ever on a Grade V, or your first trip skiing on a black diamond.

I would advise the following for "first hikes":

- Hike no more than five miles
- Test a mile walk with your planned shoe/sock combo ahead of time
- Eat more than you think you need.  Hiking can burn a lot of calories
- Make a written checklist for gear
- Hike a well traveled and populated area so that you can get help if needed
- Avoid extremes of cold/heat/weather

Unless you are going with an experienced partner, then a long/backcountry hike your first time out is a serious mistake.  You have to ramp up not just your body, but your experience.  You have to make sure your gear works.  Start with short 2-3 mile hikes and increase distance/remoteness as you gain experience.

Adapted from:  [How far is a reasonable distance for someone to hike on their first trip?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/how-far-is-a-reasonable-distance-for-someone-to-hike-on-their-first-trip/3721#3721)

Also see this related community wiki: [First time camping, need advice](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/854/first-time-camping-need-advice)

Comment: "Eat more than you think you need. Hiking can burn a lot of calories" - oh, so that's the best part of hiking then? thanks for the heads-ups and for the links

Comment: If you're planning an overnight, don't make a long hike into the back country with untested gear.  Start by sleeping overnight in your back yard, or a campground you can drive to (and drive home if it gets to be too much).  Likewise, wear your hiking gear for short walks, and gradually work up to half a day or more.

Comment: Also, don´t start your first experience in extreme conditions. Get used to mild temperatures first before you deal with heat, snow, dehydration and so on. I recommend 15-25 °C for the first time.